# Is there any way to add listener to Guava Cache which listen to updates to internal objects?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I know we can attach listener to Guava Cache which will listen the removal events. But is there any way to listen updates to the cache elements ?

Use case :
I want to make my data base in consistent state. So when an object from cache is updated I need to write back to my data base.

***Following is my sample code snippet :***

**Main class**

```
public class TestCaching {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Employee emp = getEmpUsingGuava(1);
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            // Update the 'A' Employee
            emp.setName(emp.getName() + " this is new");
            emp = getEmpUsingGuava(2);
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            // Update the 'B' Employee
            emp.setName(emp.getName() + " this is new");
            emp = getEmpUsingGuava(1);
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            emp = getEmpUsingGuava(2);
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            emp = getEmpUsingGuava(3);
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            emp = getEmpUsingGuava(1);
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Employee getEmpUsingGuava(int id) throws ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("\nGetting employee by Id :- " + id);
        LoadingCache<Integer, Employee> empCache = EmployeeGuavaCacheUtil.getLoadingCache();
        System.out.println("Cache Size:" + empCache.size());
        return empCache.get(id);
    }
}
```

**Employee class**

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeCacheUtil class**

```
public class EmployeeGuavaCacheUtil {
    private static LoadingCache<Integer, Employee> empCache;
    static {
        empCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(2).expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(new EmployeeCacheLoader());
    }
    public static LoadingCache<Integer, Employee> getLoadingCache() {
        return empCache;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeCacheLoader class**

```
public class EmployeeCacheLoader extends CacheLoader<Integer, Employee> {
    @Override
    public Employee load(Integer id) throws Exception {
        return getEmployeeById(id);
    }
    public static Employee getEmployeeById(int id) {
        System.out.println("Getting employee...");
        Employee emp1 = new Employee(1, "A");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(2, "B");
        Employee emp3 = new Employee(3, "C");
        Employee emp4 = new Employee(4, "D");
        switch (id) {
        case 1:
            return emp1;
        case 2:
            return emp2;
        case 3:
            return emp3;
        case 4:
            return emp4;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Following is output when i run the program :

```
Getting employee by Id :- 1
Cache Size:0
Getting employee...
A

Getting employee by Id :- 2
Cache Size:1
Getting employee...
B

Getting employee by Id :- 1
Cache Size:2
A this is new

Getting employee by Id :- 2
Cache Size:2
B this is new

Getting employee by Id :- 3
Cache Size:2
Getting employee...
C

Getting employee by Id :- 1
Cache Size:2
Getting employee...
A
```

See when I update the 'A' and 'B' employee, I want to update it to my DataBase. Cached 'A' and 'B' gets updated and returned correctly.

**Note** : This is sample code got from google search and changed according to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are interested is the [proposed Guava feature, CacheWriter](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2077) albeit one that can listen to changes to the objects as well.

Generally, people would use an ORM layer such as hibernate to cover this use case, I do not think there is a way to handle this using Guava alone.

**Edit:** I just discovered that [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Writer) has write-back capability. Note that caffeine has some limited compatibility with Guava Caches.